# How do hiring managers conduct background check? Or they don't?

Tags: hiring-process, background-check

Recently I went on LinkedIn to look for job, and I saw that some of the jobs have way more than 100 applicants. I am curious, what is the process like for hiring managers to conduct background checks on these applicants? I will think that the hiring managers do not do background checks on all of the applicants. But even if they select 10 or 20 candidates, do hiring managers call or email each and every of the previous workplaces or schools that are listed on the resume of these candidates? It is a labour-intensive process, I think, for hiring managers to do that. So I think that hiring managers do not check everything on the resume, but only choose one or two to check?

Also, in my country it is not common to for applicants to submit references, so contacting references is not really a way to do background check here.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, hiring managers, HR teams, or contracted companies do perform background checks, and call references.

Usually this occurs towards the end of the filtering process. Sometimes this occurs even after an offer is made (with the understanding that the offer can be withdrawn if there are discrepancies).

I also want to throw out there that there is usually a distinction between a reference check, which speaks to a candidates character and contains opinion, and an employment history check, which just verifies that the employee was employed by that company (factual).

Comment: There are also criminal background checks (most often used to check that someone who is going to be working with children isn't a sex offender), as well as security clearance checks for certain government positions.